# Factoring a polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I have a question regarding the factorisation of $f(x) = x^4 - 3x^2 + 2x + 1 \in \mathbb Q[x]$. Because of Theorem I, the only rational roots of $f(x)$ are $\pm 1$. By substituting them we see that they are no roots. Thus $f(x)$ has no linear factors.
So if $f(x)$ could be written as a product of irreducible factors, then they must have degree two. Because of Theorem II (*here is where I don't understand why Theorem II applies*) we could choose the factors such that they have integer coefficients. We suppose
\begin{align*}
 x^4 - 3x^2 + 2x + 1 & = (x^2 + ax + b)(x^2 + cx + d) \\
                     & = x^4 + (a+c)x^3 + (b+d+ac)x^2 + (bc + ad)x + bd.
\end{align*}
By comparing coefficients whe find
$$
  a + c = 0, \quad b + d + ac = -3, \quad bc + ad = 2, \quad bd = 1.
$$
These equations have no common integer solution, because of $bd = 1$ it must $b = d = \pm 1$ and then $b(a+c) = \pm 2$ in contradiction to $a+c=0$. Hence the polynomial $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x]$ and therefore also in $\mathbb Q[x]$.

**Theorem I**: Let $R$ be a UFD and let $K$ be his field of quotients. Let $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \ldots + a_n x^n \in R[x]$. If $\frac{r}{s} \in K$ with $r,s \in R, s \ne 0$, $r$ and $s$ coprime and $p(\frac{r}{s}) = 0$, then $r \mid a_0$ and $s \mid a_n$.

**Theorem II**: Let $R$ be a UFD and let $K$ be his field of quotients. Then

(i) For every $g(x) \in K[x] \setminus \{ 0 \}$ there exists $a \in K$ with $g_1(x) = ag(x) \in R[x]$ and $g_1(x)$ is primitive.

(ii) If $f(x), g(x) \in R[x]$ and $g(x)$ primitive, the following implication holds
$$
 f(x) = ag(x) \textrm{ with $a \in K$} \Rightarrow a \in R
$$

---

In the proof, where Theorem II is applied, I don't understand why we can suppose that the coefficients are integer, because when I look at Theorem II it must be the case that by changing the coefficients to an integer we multiply every coefficient (by the common denominator), but then a normed polynomial is no longer normed in general, but the polynomials in the factorisation are assumed to be normed?

Answer (score 1):

If $f=ab$, and $\mu_a$ resp. $\mu_b$ is the leading coefficient of $a$ resp. $b$, then $1=\mu_a \mu_b$. It follows $f=(\mu_a^{-1} a) (\mu_b^{-1} b)$ is a factorization into monic, in particular primitive polynomials. Does this answer your question?

See also [Gauss's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29).

Comment: but why are the coefficient of $\mu_a^{-1} a$ and $\mu_b^{-1} b$ integer numbers? there is division involed...

Comment: Have you looked at the link? It doesn't seem to work only with "Theorem II" (which is trivial).